# Spatial Analyst's CostPath toolbox/function has PATHCOST of 0 when using in_memory workspace

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst

I have a point feature and am interested in finding the least cost path between two points in the feature using a raster as the cost surface. I first calculate the cost distance and cost backlink via the CostDistance tool. I then use the CostPath tool to get the actual path and then look at the PATHCOST attribute for the raster cell's with value 3.

What I do not understand is if I run the CostPath tool with output workspace pointed at a GDB, the PATHCOST comes out as expected. When I run the CostPath tool using `in_memory` (this is actually part of a script) as the output workspace, the PATHCOST values always come out to zero. I've debugged this until I was able to pintpoint this as culprit, happening in ArcMap as well, not just the script environment.

Comment: 3 years later I have the same problem. unfortunately nobody answered...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/91006)

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented bug: [Bug BUG-000083280 Using in_memory workspaces causes the PATHCOST field to result in zero values.](http://support.esri.com/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4MzI4MA==)